# Octave - 'csvread' imports all the data in just one row

Tags: octave

As is suggested by the title. I have a csv file with 485 rows and 13 columns. When I use csvread to import the data to a variable. The variable created is 1x65821 instead of 13x485. If I use the octave's 'load data' option by right-clicking on the file, it loads a variable perfectly of 13x485 dimensions.
Here's the command that I'm using. Please suggest if there is a fallacy in my usage.

`data = csvread('crossvalidationdata.csv');`

Incorrectly imported data variable
[image: incorrectly imported data variable]

Octave's internal "LOAD DATA" option
[image: Octave's internal "LOAD DATA" option]

Correctly imported data variable
[image: Correctly imported data variable]

**EDIT:** Adding the first 5 rows from the file for reference.

```
-0.495743293,-0.470324816,-1.107378663,-0.157285276,-1.571269039,-0.792261582,0,-0.120889027,0.917805011,-0.620418406,1.732645912,-0.406845664,3
0.943990222,-0.470324816,0.575198566,-0.27464429,-0.879560223,2.078908275,0,8.25499358,-1.08730954,-0.620418406,-0.575961965,-0.406845664,13
5.263190768,2.121806272,-0.266090048,0.66422782,-0.385482498,-1.168137704,0,-0.120889027,-1.08730954,-0.620418406,-0.575961965,-0.406845664,2
-0.495743293,-0.470324816,0.575198566,-0.744080345,0.997935134,-0.810264357,0,-0.120889027,0.917805011,-0.620418406,1.732645912,-0.406845664,3
0.943990222,2.121806272,1.416487181,0.194791765,-1.077191313,-0.66078677,0,-0.120889027,-1.08730954,-0.620418406,-0.575961965,-0.406845664,2
```

Comment: hm, there must be something in the file that's causing this

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou If that is the case, then it should be the same with Octave's internal 'Load Data' option. But that works just fine. The variable produced is 485x13 as it should be.

Comment: I can't replicate the error with the data provided. `importdata` and `csvread` give me the same result. (13 columns).

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the error. 5821 is a very strange number... it's 1 more than 12*485, instead of the expected 13*485. Are you getting the same values in the two data arrays?

Comment: I checked my file in "vim" and the entire data was **actually** in a single row and the new line was replaced with some character. Maybe copy-pasting from Excel fiddled with the new line.
So I copied the entire data from the file and pasted it using vim. That worked. Thanks for the responses anyway.